# ReactJS: Functional component with props defined as Array but seen as Object

Tags: reactjs, typescript

When rendering `<MyComponent {...docs} />`, I kept the following error:

> TypeError: docs.map is not a function

Here is how I am rendering `<MyComponent />` from a parent class based component:

```
import * as React from 'react'
import IDoc from '../types/IDoc'

class Doc extends React.Component
{
   public render()
   {
      const docs : IDoc[] = Defs.getDef();
      // Example of map working (not doing anything just for an example)
      docs.map(x => x);

      return (
         <div>
            <MyComponent {...docs} />
         </div>
      )
   }
}
```

For some reason when I pass the `docs` array to the functional `<MyComponent/>` component, its not seen as an array. I need to convert it to an Array before using `.map()` which I would prefer to avoid:

```
import * as React from 'react'
import IDoc from '../types/IDoc'

// docs is an array isn't?
function MyComponent(docs : IDoc[] )
{

   if (Array.isArray(docs) === false)
   {
     //Its not seen as an array so falls into this 
      return (
         <div>
            { Object.keys(docs).map((index) => {
               const doc : IDoc = docs[index];
               const name = doc.name;
               return (
                  <div>{name}</div>
               )
               })
            }
         </div>
      )
   }else
   {
      // what I expected to work but it throws the error
      return (
         <div>
            { docs.map((doc) => {
               return (
                  <div>{doc.name}</div>
               )
               })
            }
         </div>
      )
   }
}
```

I thought as I defined docs props as `IDocs[]` it would have been seen as an array due to the square brackets.

The workaround above works, but obviously I don't want to do this every time I use an array function like `map()`. I am new to React so would appreciate any pointers. I used *create-react-app my-app --scripts-version=react-scripts-ts* in case that is helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently you're [spreading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) the elements of the `docs` array into the `props` of `MyComponent` by doing this:

```
<MyComponent {...docs} />
```

Consider revising your `MyComponent` function so that `docs` is accessed via it's own prop. This would mean accessings `docs` via the `props` object passed to the `MyComponent` functional component like so:

```
/* Add props argument, where docs array is an entry of props */
function MyComponent(props : { docs : IDoc[] }) {
    const { docs } = props;

    /* You can now use docs as before 
    if (Array.isArray(docs) === false)
    */
}
```

This change would require that in your `Doc` component, the `MyComponent` component is rendered by passing `docs` as a prop (rather than spreading the elements of the `docs` array directly into the props of `MyComponent`) by doing the following:

```
  return (
     <div>
        {/* Don't spread docs, but instead pass docs via docs prop */}
        <MyComponent docs={docs} />
     </div>
  )
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks very much @DacreDenny I have converted and that worked perfectly. 

You replied within 12 mins of me posting the question, it took me longer to write the question and longer still to try and solve it myself!